# How to find max value in nested lists and its index, based on column number?

Tags: python, max, nested-lists

Supose I have this list of lists:
`a = [[1, 7, 2], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 9]]`

I want to find the max value in each column, like the below output:

`"Max value of column [0]": 6 (at index [2][0])
"Max value of column [1]": 8 (at index [1][1])
"Max value of column [2]": 9 (at index [2][2])`

I tried `max(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))` but this returns `(2, [6,3,9])`, like saying that the nested list with the greatest value at its `[0]` position is the one located at index `[2]` of list `a`.

Comment: do you also need the 'coordinate' of the maximum?

Comment: If you mean the index, yes, because I need them in another function

Answer (score 4):

Transpose your list with `zip` and call `max` on every "sub-tuple".

```
>>> a = [[1, 7, 2], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 9]]
>>> map(max, zip(*a))
[6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @RahulKP please only edit posts when you know what you are doing. `zip` returns a list of tuples (or an iterator over tuples in Python 3), not lists.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` to the rescue

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
for k, i, m in  zip(df.columns, df.idxmax(), df.max()):

    print('"Max value of column [%i]": %i (at index [%i][%i]' % (k, m, k, i))
```

If you want to reuse the 'coordinate' of the maximum later, you could do something like

```
result = {k: (i, m,)  for k, i, m in  zip(df.columns, df.idxmax(), df.max()) }
```

or

```
result = {k: {'index': i, 'max': m,}  for k, i, m in  zip(df.columns, df.idxmax(), df.max()) }
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `numpy`,

```
In [27]: a = [[1, 7, 2], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 9]]
In [28]: import numpy as np
In [29]: an = np.array(a)
In [30]: np.max(an,axis=0)
Out[30]: array([6, 8, 9])
```

And your desired final output with `list comprehension` + `numpy`

```
["Max value of column [%s]: %s (at index [%s][%s])" %(np.where(an == item)[1][0],item,np.where(an == item)[0][0],np.where(an == item)[1][0]) for item in np.max(an,axis=0)]
```

Without using `list comprehension`,

```
for item in np.max(an,axis=0):
   indexs = np.where(an == item) 
   print "Max value of column [%s]: %s (at index [%s][%s])" %(indexs[0][0],item,indexs[0][0],indexs[1][0])
```

**Result:**

```
['Max value of column [0]: 6 (at index [2][0])',
 'Max value of column [1]: 8 (at index [1][1])',
 'Max value of column [2]: 9 (at index [2][2])']
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like *@timegeb*'s answer with `zip`, but a more by-hand alternative, assuming that all the arrays are the same length:

```
a = [[1, 7, 2], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 9]]
maxArray = []
for i in range(len(a[0])):
    maxArray.append(max([x[i] for x in a]))
print(maxArray)           # prints [6,8,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of transposing your list and getting the max value:

```
a = [[1, 7, 2], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 9]]

[max([item[k] for item in a]) for k in range(len(a))]
```